# Logging works with multiprocessing but not with loky

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing

I'm trying to produce log outputs to stdout from a function which is passed to multiprocessing/loky. Logging works only for multiprocessing, but not for loky. In contrast, printing works for both. I'd like to understand what the key difference between the two frameworks is, which causes this. Also, how can I fix it?

Example:

```py
import multiprocessing
from loky import get_reusable_executor
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('')
f_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
f_format = logging.Formatter('> %(name)s - %(message)s')
f_handler.setFormatter(f_format)
logger.addHandler(f_handler)

logger.setLevel('INFO')

def func(*args):
    print('Print in func.', flush=True)
    logger.info('Logger in func.')
```

**`multiprocessing`**

```py
logger.name = 'multiprocessing'
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
pool.map(func, range(2))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

which prints:

```
Print in func.
Print in func.
> multiprocessing - Logger in func.
> multiprocessing - Logger in func.
```

---

**`loky`**

```py
logger.name = 'loky'
executor = get_reusable_executor(max_workers=2, timeout=2)
list(executor.map(func, range(2)))
```

which prints:

```
Print in func.
Print in func.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Fork vs Fork + Exec

The `multiprocessing` and `loky` examples behave differently, since they start new processes using two different methods.

According to the [loky README](https://github.com/tomMoral/loky):

> All processes are started using fork + exec on POSIX systems. This ensures safer interactions with third party libraries. On the contrary, multiprocessing.Pool uses fork without exec by default, causing third party runtimes to crash (e.g. OpenMP, macOS Accelerate...).

The difference between using fork and fork + exec is that when only fork is used, the existing process is replicated and the newly created (child) process keeps running a copy of the original program alongside the original process. That's why your `multiprocessing` example has access to the originally configured handlers.

When fork + exec is used by `loky` (**not** on Windows, however), the forked process essentially starts a new, distinct Python interpreter, thereby losing access to many of the existing objects such as `logger`. Specifically, this happens when [fork_exec](https://github.com/tomMoral/loky/blob/98153bb460e3dfafe0d15e1a981174ebd4c85ed0/loky/backend/fork_exec.py#L36) is called in [popen_loky_posix.py](https://github.com/tomMoral/loky/blob/master/loky/backend/popen_loky_posix.py#L153), when the call to [os.execve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execve) is made.

#### Example Solution

I'm using the following (on 5.3.0-40-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 GNU/Linux):

```
Python version: 3.7.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul  1 2019, 21:52:21) 
[GCC 7.3.0]
loky version: 2.6.0
```

```
import logging
import multiprocessing
import os
from time import sleep

import loky
from loky import get_reusable_executor


def get_logger():
    print("Getting a new logger.")
    logger = logging.getLogger("")
    print("PID:", os.getpid())
    print("logger id:", id(logger))
    print("Pre-existing handlers:", logger.handlers)
    f_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    f_format = logging.Formatter("> %(name)s - %(message)s")
    f_handler.setFormatter(f_format)
    logger.addHandler(f_handler)

    logger.setLevel("INFO")

    return logger


logger = get_logger()


def func(*args):
    print("PID:", os.getpid())
    print("Print in func.", flush=True)
    logger.info("Logger in func.")


def loky_func(*args):
    # sleep(0.1)
    logger = get_logger()
    logger.name = "loky"
    print("Print in func.", flush=True)
    logger.info("Logger in func.")


def multiprocessing_logging():
    logger.name = "multiprocessing"
    logger.info("Using multiprocessing")
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    pool.map(func, range(2))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()


def loky_logging():
    logger.name = "loky"
    logger.info("Using loky")
    executor = get_reusable_executor(max_workers=2, timeout=2)
    list(executor.map(loky_func, range(2)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("-" * 82)
    multiprocessing_logging()
    print("-" * 82)
    loky_logging()
```

Running the above yields:

```
Getting a new logger.
PID: 31034
logger id: 140272374338728
Pre-existing handlers: []
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> multiprocessing - Using multiprocessing
PID: 31070
Print in func.
PID: 31071
Print in func.
> multiprocessing - Logger in func.
> multiprocessing - Logger in func.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> loky - Using loky
Getting a new logger.
PID: 31076
logger id: 139836973549720
Pre-existing handlers: []
Print in func.
> loky - Logger in func.
Getting a new logger.
PID: 31076
logger id: 139836973549720
Pre-existing handlers: [<StreamHandler <stderr> (NOTSET)>]
Print in func.
> loky - Logger in func.
> loky - Logger in func.
```

So getting and configuring a new logger within the `loky` worker function `loky_func` is a possible workaround.

What is interesting is that `loky` chooses not to spawn 2 processes at all (as opposed to `multiprocessing`), as can be seen from the identical PID and logger id numbers in the `loky` section output. A consequence of this is that the previous logger is reused, causing 2 `StreamHandler` handlers to be present the second time `loky_func` is run (thus the duplicated output).

If we modify `loky_func` like so:

```
def loky_func(*args):
    sleep(0.1)  # 'Long' computation.
    logger = get_logger()
    logger.name = "loky"
    print("Print in func.", flush=True)
    logger.info("Logger in func.")
```

we find that the corresponding output is now

```
> loky - Using loky
Getting a new logger.
PID: 31390
logger id: 140144439347296
Pre-existing handlers: []
Print in func.
> loky - Logger in func.
Getting a new logger.
PID: 31391
logger id: 140330455283864
Pre-existing handlers: []
Print in func.
> loky - Logger in func.
```

indicating that now, 2 processes are spawned. Each retrieved its own logger and added the correct handlers to it, resulting in the expected behaviour.

To make this approach more robust you would have to inspect and modify  the list of handlers `logger.handlers` instead of simply adding handlers indiscriminately. Making such an approach thread and process safe would require some more tools such as [multiprocessing.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) when using `multiprocessing` or a shared Queue using [multiprocessing.Manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-managers) when using `loky` (but there are probably more efficient methods).

The logging package [loguru](https://github.com/Delgan/loguru) implements the former approach for logging to files (using a Queue when given the `enqueue=True` parameter in `logger.add`) and thereby allows thread and process safe logging when using `multiprocessing`. Since it doesn't use multiprocessing Managers, however, this approach breaks when using `loky`. This can be fixed (rather hackishly) by manually supplying a shared Manager Queue as an argument to the `loky` worker functions and then using this to set up the handlers therein.